# Adjusting the height of ui-view element[Angular.js Angular UI Router]

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular.js and angular-ui-router. There is a little problem with the height of the ui-view element. It is fixed to the height of view-port rather then its content. As the content updates dynamically the height of the content changes but that of the parent ui-view element remains the same.. Due to which the height of the body element also remains the same as that of the ui-view. How to cater this problem

```
<body> 
    <div ui-view>
        <div id = "content"> 
            <!-- Some content with height more then that of view-port -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is not an angularjs issue; it's a CSS issue.  Check your CSS rules.

Comment: I've tried multiple options but all in vain.. like setting the min-height to 100%. What else can I try..

Comment: You'd have to post your css for us to have any idea what's going on.  If you can post a jsfiddle or plunkr that shows the problem then it will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS issue, not an Angular issue. Your body probably has a height set to 100%. Setting it to

```
body {
    height: auto;
}
```

will fix it.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height):

> A percentage height on the root element is relative to the **initial** containing block.

Answer (score 1):

I created an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vDY3mQR2ydBs6QLJZiJr?p=preview) with a basic layout. It should show or give some answers how to use UI-Router, HTML and CSS. The idea of layout is:

- fixed top bar
- fixed left column
- dynamic central area

inte *index.html* `<div ui-view=""></div>` we inject **layout.tpl**:

```
<div>
  <section class="top">
    <div ui-view="top"></div>
  </section>

  <section class="middle">

    <section class="left">
      <div ui-view="left"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="main">
      <div ui-view="main"></div>
    </section>

  </section>
</div>
```

And these are styles:

```
.top { background: #bcd;
position: absolute; height: 100px; width: auto; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: auto;
}
.middle {
position: absolute; height: auto; width: auto; left: 0; right: 0; top: 100px; bottom: 0;
}
.left { background: #def;
position: absolute; height: auto; width: 200px; left: 0; right: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
.main { 
position: absolute; height: auto; width: auto; left: 200px; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

And these are `states` for this simple app:

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    views: {
      '@' : {
        templateUrl: 'layout.html',
      },
      'top@app' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.top.html',},
      'left@app' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.left.html',},
      'main@app' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.main.html',},
    },
  })
.state('app.list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
  })
.state('app.list.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    views: {
      'detail@app' : {
        templateUrl: 'detail.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
      },
    },
  })
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vDY3mQR2ydBs6QLJZiJr?p=preview)